# Explain the first parameter of the Subtotal function

Tags: excel-formula

I have a **formula** `Subtotal(9,C2:C500)` in a spreadsheet I received from a client.  I am unfamiliar with the meaning of the first parameter, `9`.

Comment: From the [official docs](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939) it means it's using the `SUM` function as the accumulator for the data range C2 and C500

Comment: [First hit on google..](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60392&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

From the excel help, it is a sum function for cells C2 to C500 **including** the results or values in manually hidden rows as per the screenshot (direct from the excel help):

[image]